# Skin overlay doesn't appear on servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My MC skin overlay appears fine in singleplayer, but when I log into a server, it doesn't show. I checked my skin customization options and everything is on, so why won't the overlay show in servers? My skin looks kind of stupid without it.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally this can happen with some servers that support version 1.7.10. I fixed it by simply going to the menu and going to video settings, and then back to the game straight away. Hope this helped!